# SQL Count not working correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sccm

I am trying to use the query below to get a list of software programs and the count of computers it is installed on. So the output would be like

```
Count (computers)   Software
55                  Microsoft Outlook
```

When I use the query below it gives me a count but I don't think its the count I am looking for. So if the software is installed on 55 computers it would return that count. TIA

```
SELECT COUNT(c.Name0),
       a.DisplayName0
FROM   v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS a,
       v_R_System c
WHERE  A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'hotfix for%'
       AND A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'Security Update for%'
GROUP  BY a.DisplayName0
ORDER  BY COUNT(c.Name0)
```

Comment: How are you joining the tables `v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS` and `v_R_System`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this is an SCCM database and c.Name = Computer Name

Comment: What are the columns of each of these tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a join predicate between the two tables.  Is the reference to v_R_System necessary?

If not you can just use

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
       a.DisplayName0
FROM   v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS a
WHERE  A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'hotfix for%'
       AND A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'Security Update for%'
GROUP  BY a.DisplayName0
ORDER  BY COUNT(*);
```

If it is necessary you will need to add a join predicate between the tables.

Comment: I think its necessary as I get an error The multi-part identifier "c.Name0" could not be bound.

Comment: If I don't do the count, it returns a computer name for each software program which is too many rows

Comment: If you remove the table, you'd need to remove the references to it also.  Replace the COUNT(c.Name0) with COUNT(*)

Comment: Like this? SELECT COUNT(*), a.DisplayName0 FROM v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS a

Comment: Something like this: SELECT COUNT(*), a.DisplayName0 FROM v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS a 
WHERE  A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'hotfix for%'
AND A.DisplayName0 NOT LIKE 'Security Update for%'
GROUP BY a.DisplayName0
ORDER BY COUNT(*)